# Passing the list of strings as input to a function

Tags: r, function

I am trying automate a simple task in R using a function.
`C` is list of character variables. `mydata`- is the dataset.

Basically, I need to give each of the strings in vector `C` as an input to the function.

dataset:

```
mydata <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), b = c(4L,3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L), c = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L), d = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), t = c(42L, 34L, 74L,39L, 47L, 8L, 36L, 39L), s = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "t", "s"), row.names = c(NA,8L), class = "data.frame")
```

code:

```
c<-c("a","b","c","d")

plot<-function()
 for (i in c) 
{
  fit<-survfit(Surv(s,t)~paste(i), dat=mydata)
  ggsurvplot(fit, pval = TRUE)  
}
plot()
```

I m facing the following error:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = Surv(mydata$s, mydata$t) ~
>   paste(i),  :    variable lengths differ (found for 'paste(i)')

I have tried the reformulate as well:

plot<-function()
     for (i in c) 
    {
      survfit(update(Surv(s,t)~., reformulate(i)), data=mydata)
      ggsurvplot(fit, pval = TRUE)
    }
    plot()

but this code also gives this error:

```
Error in reformulate(i) : object 'i' not found
```

Any help to make this code work?

Thanks

Comment: It's easier to help when you provide some sort of [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can actually run and test code.

Comment: thanks for the comment. sample input data is provided

Answer (score 1):

Building formulas dynamically can be tricky. Rather than

```
fit(Surv(mydata$s,mydata$t)~paste(i), dat=mydata)
```

use

```
fit(update(Surv(s,t)~., reformulate(i)), data=mydata)
```

You should avoid using `$` with formulas. Here `reformualte()` helps to build a formula from a string and `update` combines parts of formulas. See the help pages for these functions if you would like more details.

Here's the full working version with the sample inout

```
#sample input
mydata <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), b = c(4L,3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L), c = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L), d = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), t = c(42L, 34L, 74L,39L, 47L, 8L, 36L, 39L), s = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "t", "s"), row.names = c(NA,8L), class = "data.frame") 
c<-c("a","b","c","d")
```

and the code

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

plot <- function() {
    for (i in c) { 
        fit <- survfit(update(Surv(t,s)~., reformulate(i)), data=mydata)
        ggsurvplot(fit)
    }
}
plot()
```

When I copy/paste that into R I do not get any errors. You must be doing something different than the sample code you've posted.

Comment: Thanks but the code exists with the following error:                                   Error in reformulate(i) : object 'i' not found

Comment: Your example had `for (i in c)`. Did you not keep that part? How did you get an error about `SEX` when that's no where in your example?

Comment: Yes, I kept that for condition) as well.  I tried with the complete version of the dataset. So, that error message

Comment: I tested my answer again and it works. I've included the complete code block above. You should be able to copy/paste that into a new R session and verify it works.